# Confusion over 'require login' behavior

Tags: login

Quote from the {% requireLogin %} docs:

> This tag will ensure that the user is logged in. If they aren’t, they
>   will be redirected to the Login page, and returned to the original
>   page after successfully logging in.

Quote from the Login Form example in the docs:

> craft.session.returnUrl is set to the original URL that included the {% requireLogin %} tag that initiated the redirect to this login form. By default, users will be redirected based on your postLoginRedirect config setting value after logging in.

That seems to be contradictory - the first sentence saying the return path will be the page that contained the requireLogin tag and the second saying the return path is defined by a config setting.

I want to be able to have the redirect go to the page that calls the login (I have 
 a few of them), but do not see a way of doing that. Using a return parameter in the login form does not work for obvious reasons.

Am I missing something here? Any wisdom greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

By default Craft checks the postLoginRedirect setting in your config. Depending on this value the user is going to be redirected to certain place. But if there is a value in the user session that's set when the `requireLogin` function is called Yii2 will use this value instead. So the workflow is the following

1. Check for a session value, if there is one, redirect the user
2. Check for `postLoginRedirect` value, if there is one, redirect the user
3. Redirect to homepage

> Using a return parameter in the login form does not work for obvious reasons.

Could you explain those obvious reasons? Because I always use the `returnUrl` from `UsersController` when I create a login via ajax.

You don't have to do anything actually. Just include the Twig token and Yii2 will handle it

Comment: Thanks, Robin. I have a number of different pages that use requireLogin, so the redirect needs to be set dynamically, which is why I can't hard code it into the login form set it in the postLoginRedirect in my config file. What Twig token are you referring to?

Comment: The `{% requireLogin %}` token will exactly do that for you. When a user enters a page with that token and is a guest (not logged in) the current route is stored in the session and the user will be redirected to your login. After a successful login yii2 will grab the session value and redirect the user back to the route where he was before / to the site he was going to see before he/she  logged in

Comment: Yes, that is the way it is supposed to work, but it doesn't, which is why I posted this question. The return is the home page, no matter what. Note that craft/src/GeneralConfig has this:  public $postLoginRedirect = ' '; On lastest version of Craft 3

Comment: You may want to submit a bug report or something. I use the tag in many projects and it always works, even in the latest version of Craft. Do you have some custom code or a plugin that might interfere? Also: do you submit the form normally or via Ajax? Do you use a custom Controller or `users/login`